# Querying API Loop VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, api, loops, isbn

I am attempting to create a home-library database program. I have a barcode scanner and want to be able to look up the book's ISBN online and add the title and author to a Microsoft Access file. I have every part of my code working except the following:

```
Public Sub XMLStuff()
For i = 0 To UBound(aryISBN) - 1
        ' If the ISBN exists
        If (aryISBN(i).Chars(1) <> "#") Then
            GETXML(i, aryISBN)
            ReadXML(Title, Author, intCount)
        Else
            MsgBox("this is not a valid isbn")
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Public Sub GETXML(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal aryISBN As String())
    Dim accessKey As String = "NUMBER"
    ' URL for isbndb.com API
    Dim url As String = ("https://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=" + accessKey + "&results=texts&index1=isbn&value1=" + aryISBN(i))
    ' Create new XML reader from URL
    Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(url)

    ' Delete XML file if it already exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(FILE_NAME)
    End If

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, False)

    ' Write entire XML output to file
    Do While (reader.Read())
        Select Case reader.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.
                objWriter.Write("<" + reader.Name)
                objWriter.WriteLine(">")
            Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
                objWriter.WriteLine(reader.Value)
            Case XmlNodeType.EndElement 'Display end of element.
                objWriter.Write("</" + reader.Name)
                objWriter.WriteLine(">")
        End Select
    Loop
    objWriter.Close()
    reader.Close()
End Sub
```

When I have two valid ISBNs in the array, the first array always returns the full XML (first example that follows) but the second ISBN always returns the wrong XML (second following example). I have directly tested each ISBN in my browser so I know what XML should be returned the second time. Did I do something wrong with my loop?

```
<ISBNdb>
<BookList>
<BookData isbn="1612510248">
<Title>...</Title>
<TitleLong>...</TitleLong>
<AuthorsText>...</AuthorsText>
</BookData>
</BookList>
</ISBNdb>

<ISBNdb>
<BookList>
</BookList>
</ISBNdb>
```

Comment: Nevermind I found the error. When I was splitting the ISBNs into an array, they had a line break at the beginning of the string (starting with the second entry) that was causing the URL to be wrong.